# Eclipse Juno C++ Binary not found?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I am getting this error. Launch Failed, binary not found.

I am new to C++, so I am unsure where to start with this.. it was compiling until I added "swap".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Binary not found" is the result of a failing compilation - check the compiler output, it says `assignment of read-only reference`. That's because you cannot assign to variable `str`, since it's declared as `const` parameter to the `permute` method.

The solution depends on how your method should work:

- If `permute` should modify the variable given as parameter `str` (i.e. the string you use as parameter when `permute` is called), then remove the `const` in the method declaration
- If you only use `str` inside the method, and the string variable used for the method call should remain unchanged, then create a copy of it (e.g. `std::string strCopy(str);`) and work with that instead of `str`.